# Copying files from a folder with a pattern

Tags: nsis

As part of my installer I'm extracting a JRE which is in a folder that varies name (i.e. jre1.8.0_74). I'm trying to do that with a pattern, but it can't find it. I tried something like this:

```
  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\${APPDIR}\jre"
  ${If} ${RunningX64}
    File /nonfatal /a /r "${SrcDir}\jre\jre_64\jre*\*.*"
  ${Else}
    File /nonfatal /a /r "${SrcDir}\jre\jre_32\jre*\*.*"
  ${EndIf}
```

But found no files. I basically want to skip this "unknown" folder name to make it easier starting my application, etc.

I know it's a NSIS newbie basic mistake somewhere :P

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

When something is not known at compile-time you must use `!system` to execute a batch file or something else that is able to create a text file with the desired NSIS instruction that you later can `!include`.

For filesystem wildcards you can probably get away with just using `dir` or `for`:

```
!macro InvokeNSISCommandOnWildcardFolder parentdir wildcard commandprefix commandsuffix
!tempfile _InvokeNSISCommandOnWildcardFolder
!system 'for /D %A in ("${parentdir}\${wildcard}") do @(^>^> "${_InvokeNSISCommandOnWildcardFolder}" echo ${commandprefix}${parentdir}\%~nxA${commandsuffix})'
!include "${_InvokeNSISCommandOnWildcardFolder}"
!delfile "${_InvokeNSISCommandOnWildcardFolder}"
!undef"${_InvokeNSISCommandOnWildcardFolder}"
!macroend

Section
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\${APPDIR}\jre"
!insertmacro InvokeNSISCommandOnWildcardFolder "${SrcDir}\jre\jre_32" "jre*" 'File /nonfatal /a /r "' '\*.*"'
SectionEnd
```

Because my example here just uses !system to invoke "DOS" commands directly there are some restrictions on the strings passed to this macro and `<`, `>`, `(`, and `)` might have to be escaped.